# How to access the variable outside function in python

Tags: python, function

Below function creates a data frame with monthly returns and also modifies the portfolio basis certain parameters. e.g. out of the list of 500 stocks function creates a portfolio of 50 best performing stocks and function returns the monthly profit of portfolio.

### How do I access the portfolio[list] outside the function.

#### portfolio = portfolio + new_picks

```
def pflio(DF,m,x):
  # Returns cumulative portfolio return
  # DF = dataframe with monthly return info for all stocks
  # m = number of stock in the portfolio
  # x = number of underperforming stocks to be removed from portfolio monthly
            
  df = DF.copy()
  portfolio = []
  monthly_ret = [0]
  for i in range(1,len(df)):
     if len(portfolio) > 0:
          monthly_ret.append(df[portfolio].iloc[i,:].mean())
          bad_stocks = df[portfolio].iloc[i,:].sort_values(ascending=True) 
          [:x].index.values.tolist()
          portfolio = [t for t in portfolio if t not in bad_stocks]
      fill = m - len(portfolio)
      new_picks = df.iloc[i,:].sort_values(ascending=False
      [:fill].index.values.tolist()
      portfolio = portfolio + new_picks
      print(portfolio)  
   monthly_ret_df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(monthly_ret),columns=["mon_ret"])
   return monthly_ret_df
```

Comment: you would need to return it to use the value outside the function. I recommend learning about scopes.

Comment: Can you fix your format: code must be put into codebox and you shouldn't bolt all the text!

Answer (score 0):

You can replace two last line of the function with `return portfolio`

```
def pflio(DF,m,x):
    # Returns cumulative portfolio return
    # DF = dataframe with monthly return info for all stocks
    # m = number of stock in the portfolio
    # x = number of underperforming stocks to be removed from portfolio monthly
    
    df = DF.copy()
    portfolio = []
    monthly_ret = [0]
    for i in range(1,len(df)):
        if len(portfolio) > 0:
            monthly_ret.append(df[portfolio].iloc[i,:].mean())
            bad_stocks = df[portfolio].iloc[i,:].sort_values(ascending=True) 
            [:x].index.values.tolist()
            portfolio = [t for t in portfolio if t not in bad_stocks]
        fill = m - len(portfolio)
        new_picks = df.iloc[i,:].sort_values(ascending=False)[:fill].index.values.tolist()
        portfolio = portfolio + new_picks
        print(portfolio)  
    return portfolio
```